# CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer bounds contains NaN: [0 0; nan nan] crash in view

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, animation, crash

I've looked a lot into this, but I can only seem to get webView and tables relating to this issue.  Mine's totally different it seems with the same crash exception:

CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer bounds contains NaN: [0 0; nan nan]

Basically what I have here is a view that fades and scales images. I've recently decided to change my code using CGAffineTransformScale in a UIView animation instead of scaling things up a notch every time a timer ticks. This uses way less processing power.

But no matter what order I have the pictures in, it always crashes after the 19th one.  It does not seem to be an issue with the positioning coordinate array that it refers to, because it is only 6 in length and loops over after it reaches its length.  So for some reason now since I've implemented this animation code it gives me that crash.  Anyone know why?

Here's the part I've changed since it started crashing:

```
-(void) onTimer{

if(scaleTimer_A==5){

    imageView_A.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[attractList_A objectAtIndex:imageIndex_A]];

    imageView_A.frame = CGRectMake(300, 200, 3.86, 3.86);

    imageView_A.center = CGPointMake(attractLocs_x_A[attractLocs_A_index], attractLocs_y_A[attractLocs_A_index]);



    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
    imageView_A.alpha = 1;
    imageView_A.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(imageView_A.transform, 100, 100);
    [UIView commitAnimations]; 
}

if(scaleTimer_A==10){

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.75];
    imageView_A.alpha = 0;
    imageView_A.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(imageView_A.transform, 1.2, 1.2);
    [UIView commitAnimations]; 

    scaleTimer_A=0;

    imageIndex_A+=1;

    if(imageIndex_A==imageIndex_A_size){
        imageIndex_A=0;
    }

    attractLocs_A_index+=1;

    if(attractLocs_A_index==attractLocs_A_SIZE){
        NSLog(@"Back to zero A");
        attractLocs_A_index=0;
    }
    NSLog(@"Image A =%@", [attractList_A objectAtIndex:imageIndex_A]);
}

scaleTimer_A+=1;}
```

**EDIT**:

Here's how I got the code above to work without the crashing problem using CGAffineTransformIdentity.

```
-(void) onTimer{

if(scaleTimer_A==5){

    imageView_A.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[attractList_A objectAtIndex:imageIndex_A]];

    imageView_A.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    imageView_A.center = CGPointMake(attractLocs_x_A[attractLocs_A_index], attractLocs_y_A[attractLocs_A_index]);



    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
    imageView_A.alpha = 1;
    imageView_A.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 100, 100);
    [UIView commitAnimations]; 
}

if(scaleTimer_A==10){

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.75];
    imageView_A.alpha = 0;
    imageView_A.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 120, 120);
    [UIView commitAnimations]; 

    scaleTimer_A=0;

    imageIndex_A+=1;

    if(imageIndex_A==imageIndex_A_size){
        imageIndex_A=0;
    }

    attractLocs_A_index+=1;

    if(attractLocs_A_index==attractLocs_A_SIZE){
        NSLog(@"Back to zero A");
        attractLocs_A_index=0;
    }
    NSLog(@"Image A =%@", [attractList_A objectAtIndex:imageIndex_A]);
}

scaleTimer_A+=1;}
```

Comment: NaN normally occurs when you divide by zero. Go through and double check all your math.

Comment: I've heard this too, but where in this code am I dividing by 0?

Comment: can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Crap.. sorry that was completely the wrong log.. HOLD ON

Comment: ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer bounds contains NaN: [0 0; nan nan]'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x009ddbe9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x015a15c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x00996628 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
 3   CoreFoundation                      0x0099659a +[NSException raise:format:] + 58
 4   QuartzCore                          0x0079a3ee _ZL16CALayerSetBoundsP7CALayerRKN2CA4RectEb + 227

Comment: 5   QuartzCore                          0x0079a2b6 -[CALayer setBounds:] + 122
 6   UIKit                               0x00e0c307 -[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:] + 255
 7   UIKit                               0x00ea03aa -[UIImageView setFrame:] + 167
 8   TE SubCom                           0x0000b49f -[dynamicViewViewController onTimer] + 713
 9   Foundation                          0x00b6c7a5 __NSFireTimer + 125
 10  CoreFoundation                      0x009befe3 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 19

Comment: 11  CoreFoundation                      0x009c0594 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1220
 12  CoreFoundation                      0x0091ccc9 __CFRunLoopRun + 1817
 13  CoreFoundation                      0x0091c240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
 14  CoreFoundation                      0x0091c161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
 15  GraphicsServices                    0x0196f268 GSEventRunModal + 217
 16  GraphicsServices                    0x0196f32d GSEventRun + 115
 17  UIKit                               0x00de542e UIApplicationMain + 1160

Comment: 18  TE SubCom                           0x00001cee main + 84
 19  TE SubCom                           0x00001c91 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the stack trace the problem is here

```
imageView_A.frame = CGRectMake(300, 200, 3.86, 3.86);
```

Try to set the imageView_A.transform to identity. Another solution (and I think better) would be using the UIScrollView for scaling (it is also could be made animated).

Edit:  try this

```
    imageView_A.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[attractList_A objectAtIndex:imageIndex_A]];

    imageView_A.frame = CGRectMake(300, 200, 3.86, 3.86);

    imageView_A.center = CGPointMake(attractLocs_x_A[attractLocs_A_index], attractLocs_y_A[attractLocs_A_index]);



    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
    imageView_A.alpha = 1;
    imageView_A.frame = CGRectMake(300, 200, 386.0f, 386.0f);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: In my case, setting imageView_A.transform to CGAffineTransformIdentity are not equivalent. The UIScrollView does not make much sense to me, especially if I want multiple image views transforming independently. Why should the frame for imageView_A be a problem anyway?

Comment: because the crash is during setting of the imageView_A.frame

Comment: Okay, thanks. It seems to have stopped the crashing. I'll just have to figure out a work around to tweak it so it behaves like it should.

Comment: @Max How can I use CGAffineTransformIdentity with the code I have and have it behave the same way? I've tried a bunch of things. I'm stumped.

Comment: well, try scale the view like this imageView_A.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 100, 100);  But I'm not sure that it would work as expected, cause I actually don't know what end result you want to achieve.

Comment: Yeah I've tried that. Scaling animation is different and depending what settings you have it won't even display the second time around.

Comment: See my edits in opening post. Instead of setting the frame, I did imageView_A.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity; Thanks.

Comment: @Max can u please help me

Comment: @Navi how can i help u ?

Comment: Some times getting random crash any suggestion ?