# App crashing after adding scrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I added a scrollView as subView to self.view using IB but the app keep crashing with
`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer bounds contains NaN: [nan nan; 320 460]'`

IDK if I am adding a scrollView the right way. I just drag 1 scrollView out from the IB Library and enlarge it size such that it covers the entire view.

[IB http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/5104/unledcnd.png](http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/5104/unledcnd.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867968/calayerinvalidgeometry-reason-calayer-bounds-contains-nan-0-0-nan-nan-cra

Comment: Check your every IB outlet is connected or not. ?

Comment: @Jagdish. Yes, it is. It seems that adding some of the UITextView in causes the crash.

Answer (score 0):

You're putting an wrong value on some frame of a view that gets added to the scroll view...

Probably is the X and Y position of the UIScrollView, as the dimensions are 320x460.